# POST JSON to url using CURL and C

Tags: c, json, bash, curl, libcurl

I'm tring to POST JSON data to a url from bash using:

```
$ curl -v -d '{xxx:200}&apikey=xxxxx' -X POST http://localhost/xxxx/input/post.json -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type:application/json"
```

And in C using the following:

```
int main(void)
{
CURL *easyhandle; 

curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
easyhandle = curl_easy_init();

if(easyhandle) {
char *data="json={xxx:200}&apikey=xxxxx";   
curl_easy_setopt(easyhandle, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, data);   
curl_easy_setopt(easyhandle, CURLOPT_URL, "http://localhost/xxxx/input/post.json");
curl_easy_perform(easyhandle); 


curl_easy_cleanup (easyhandle);
}

curl_global_cleanup();

return 0;
}
```

This is what i'm trying to achieve actually:

```
http://localhost/xxxx/input/post.json?json={xxx:200}&apikey=xxxxx
```

It doesn't seem to work. :(
I'm a complete novice to curl. Please help.

Thanks!

Comment: The JSON data will need to be encoded before sending. I can't remember the C function for doing so but have a google.

Comment: @ScottMcGready Thanks! I'll look into that. Just wanted to know if there is something wrong with the bash command as well.

Comment: Well give the encoding to HTML entities a shot and then see what the error is. Gotta walk before you can run ;)

Comment: @ScottMcGready But it's probably a bad idea to send JSON in a GET request anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately the server I was sending the data handled POST and GET requests, so the code in question would suffice.

Others with a similar problem can use a simple workaround (If your code doesn't have real time constraints and is not performance intensive). You may fork a bash process using system() from C. This avoids you the trouble of encoding.

Answer (score -1):

What you are trying to do is not performing a POST request but performing a GET request. However, I'm not sure this is a good idea, since GET parameters are limited in length (to something like 2 kB or so), and - as others have already mentioned - they need to be encoded and decoded and all the funky stuff which is a pain in the neck.

The URL pointing to localhost suggests me that you have control over the server code. If you used the POST parameters instead of the GET ones, you could use your current code as-is (which sets the POST body of the request, which is probably the right thing to do -- so you don't have to change your client code, you only have to change the server code.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation! I'm beginning to gain some clarity.
Yes, I do have access to the server code, which is an open source project, but I haven't done any php programming myself. 
So, I'll start with the GET request for now.